# How to make an additional http call inside api and process response?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to create Message Mediation Policies, with which I can make an additional http call, process the response and enrich the current message. How can i do this? I use call Mediator, but I don’t understand how to handle the response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <sequence name="call_out_handler" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<call blocking="true">
    <endpoint>
        <http method="get" uri-template="http://192.168.99.100:8888/stubFORAPIMan/ServletWithTimeout"/>
    </endpoint>
</call> </sequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PayloadFactory Mediator [1] to handle/format the response you received by calling an endpoint inside the Call mediator.

An example would be like this. Say you want to provide a json object by populating the values from the response you received; you can define the json object format in the "format" section and populate the values by providing the arguments in the "args" section in the PayloadFactory mediator as below.

```
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
       <format>
          {
          "Data": {
          "PaymentSubmissionId": "$1",
          "PaymentId": "$2",
          "Status": "$3",
          "CreationDateTime": "$4"
          }
          } 
       </format>
       <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//PaymentSubId"/>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body//PaymentId"/>
          <arg evaluator="xml" value="AcceptedSettlementInProcess"/>
          <arg value="2019-06-05T15:15:22+00:00"/>
       </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/PayloadFactory+Mediator

Comment: This does not help, I have access to the body of the request or response message. Where is the message body received as a result of the call mediator I don’t understand, I’m unable to access it.